# How the .add_subplot(nrows, ncols, index) works?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am creating a figure in matplotlib's [add_subplot()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) function.

When I run this

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(231)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(232)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(233)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(212) # why not 211
```

I get this output

[image]

**My question is how this last argument works. Why it is 212 for ax4 instead of 211, since there is only one plot for 2nd row?**

If I run with 211 instead of 212 as following:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(231)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(232)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(233)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(211)
```

I get this output where Plot 4 places on Plot 2 on first row.

[image]

I would be appreciated if someone could explain how the indexing works. Spent quite time researching still did not get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The index `212` used here is intentional. Here the first two indices means 2 rows and 1 column. When the third number is 1 (211), it means add the subplot in the first row. When the third number is 2 (212), it means add the subplot in the second row.

The reason that in the above example, `212` is used is because the first three lines `ax1`, `ax2` and `ax3` adds subplots to a 2 row and 3 column grid. If `211` is used for the fourth subplot (`ax4`), it will overlap with the first row of `(231), (232)` and `(233)`. This can be seen in the second figure below where you see the `ax4` overlapping the underlying 3 subplots. This is the reason `ax4` is added in the second row of the 2 row 1 column figure using `(212)` instead of adding it to the first row of using `(211)`

If you use `212`, you get the following output

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(231)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(232)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(233)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(212)
```

[image]

If you use `211`, you get the following output. As you can see, the `ax4` is covering the 3 subplots.

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(231)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(232)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(233)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(211)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Thanks for clarifying. It answered my question.

Comment: You are welcome